# how to write this self join query in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, self-join

Hello I have a table structure like this

```
products_id | model_num | master_model_num
   1        |  cth001   |    0 
   2        |  cth002   |    0
   3        |  cth003   |    cth001
   4        |  cth004   |    cth001
   5        |  cth005   |    0
   6        |  cth006   |    cth002
```

**My Problem**

I will provide the `products_id` to the table and it will get all product ids whoes `master_model_num` is equal to the `model_num` of the given `products_id`

I have tried following query but it doen't generate the result that I want

```
SELECT p.products_id 
FROM products p,products pp 
WHERE p.products_id=pp.products_id 
AND p.products_model=pp.products_master_model 
AND p.products_id='1'
```

Comment: For the given example, since you have an equi-join on products_id to both tables, and the products_id is filtered to 1 at the end of your WHERE clause, you'll only receive that single record.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT pp.products_id
    FROM products p
        INNER JOIN products pp
            ON p.model_num = pp.master_model_num
    WHERE p.products_id = '1'
```

Comment: Never use explicit join syntax with MySQL, at least if you're on 5.1 or below, it will prevent the query optimizer from generating a correct plan for your query (yes, I've tested this extensively).

Comment: @PlexQ: Can you provide some evidence (blog article, bug report, etc.) of this testing? I've never heard of such a thing.

Comment: @Joe Steffanelli this is exactly what I need. +1 for this

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't

```
SELECT products_id
FROM products
WHERE master_model_num = (SELECT model_num 
                          FROM products 
                          WHERE products_id = 1)
```

make more sense in this case?  By having `AND p.products_id='1'` on the end of your query, you're guaranteeing that you'll only get one record back.

Comment: Solution without inner query. I can do it with inner query

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT 
  p.products_id 
 FROM 
   products p 
 INNER JOIN 
   products pp 
 ON 
   pp.products_master_model = p.products_model
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT p.products_id FROM products p,products pp where p.model_num=pp.master_model_num and p.products_id='1'
```