# Mysql - querying for row where column shows a name referenced from the same table

Tags: mysql

I have a self referencing table of Employees where there is a Supervisor column that stores an employee ID that references to the same table. I am trying to have a column displaying the supervisor's name instead of the ID or an extra column for the name.

Employees Table:

```
id     | first_name | last_name | gender | department   | supervisor | ....
----------------------------------------------------------------------
25     | Terrance   | Pepper    | male   | Marketing    | 2
...
......
2      | Janice     | Anderson  | female | Marketing    | NULL
```

So the outcome I would like to come out is something like this:

```
id | first_name | last_name | gender | department | supervisor | supervisor_name | ....
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
25 | Terrance   | Pepper    | male   | Marketing  | 2          | Janice Anderson
```

This query that I tried have gotten me kind of close but it's ordered incorrectly:

```
SELECT s.*
     , CONCAT(s.first_name, s.last_name) AS supervisor_name
     , ( SELECT CONCAT(first_name, last_name) 
           FROM employees 
          WHERE employee_id = 12 
          LIMIT 1
       ) AS employee_name 
  FROM employees s 
 WHERE s.employee_id = (SELECT e.supervisor 
                          FROM employees e 
                         WHERE e.employee_id = 12)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to write this self join query in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743960/how-to-write-this-self-join-query-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `self join`

```
select e.*
concat(m.first_name,m.last_name) as supervisor_name
from employees e
left join employees m
on e.supervisor=m.id
```